# Input a password from the user and check if it has a char, alphabet and digit

Tags: c, arrays, loops, char

My doubt is that, the program works fine if I enter a password that fills the array. However if I enter a password such as "apple25", I think it counts the blank spaces in the array as characters and even declares "apple25" as a valid password.

How do I prevent this from happening? Does it count the string terminator also as a `char`? Because even "AAPPLLEE2" comes as a valid password.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


int main()
{
    char arr[10];
    printf("Enter a password. \n");
    scanf("%s",arr );
   // printf(arr);
    char ch;
    int i;
    int alp=0, dig=0, c=0;


    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       ch=arr[i];

       if(isalpha(ch))
       {
           alp++;
          // printf(" alpha is %d \n",alp);
       }
       else if(isdigit(ch))
       {
           dig++;
          // printf("digit is %d \n",dig);
       }
       else
       {
           c++;
         //  printf("charectores are %d \n",c);
       }

    }
    if(alp>=1&&dig>=1&&c>=1)
        {
            printf("Valid Password");
        }
    else{
            printf("Invalid Password");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Point 1. Always initialize your automatic local variables. Saves you from accidentally accessing un-initialized value.

  ```
  char arr[10] = {0};
  ```
- Point 2. Always limit your input length. Saves you from running into [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by overrunning the allocated memory by longer-than-expected input.

  ```
  scanf("%9s",arr );
  ```
- Point 3. Use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) to loop over only the *valid* part of input.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your loop runs over the entire, not just upto the characters you read.

Instead do,

```
    size_t len = strlen(arr);

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
      ...
    }
```

You may also want to use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) to avoid buffer overrun. If you enter more than 10 characters, you'll overflow `arr`, which is *undefined behaviour.*

Instead of

```
scanf("%s",arr );
```

do

```
fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin);
char *p = strchr(arr, '\n');
if(p) *p = 0; //trim the trailing newline, if present
```

Answer (score 2):

> I think it counts the blank spaces in the array as charecters and even declares `"apple25"` as a valid password.

Your assumption is almost right. Your program does count characters after the end of user input, but they are not necessarily blanks.

You get this effect with `"AAPPLLEE2"` because your code examines ten characters of a nine-character string. The tenth character is null terminator, which is neither a digit nor a letter.

You need to use the actual length for the limit of the loop, rather than hard-coding the limit of ten.

You should also fix the potential buffer overrun:

```
char arr[11];       // <<== Add one more character for '\0'
printf("Enter a password. \n");
scanf("%10s",arr ); // <<== Tell scanf how big is your buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

- Try entering a password with a size of 10 or longer. You'd overflow `arr`.
- You don't stop at the terminating NULL character (value 0). In fact, you count the terminating NULL as "character" and increase `c` when you come across it.
- Any garbage afterward is also processed.